# How to find menu of the day if they should repeat only every month?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create my program to show me a different meal each day of the week and so far this is what i have

```
Dim dt as DateTime.Now
If dt.DayofWeek = DayofWeek.Monday then
    Textbox1.Text = "Steak with a cup of rice and Iced tea"
Elseif dt.DayofWeek = DayofWeek.Tuesday then
    Textbox1.Text = "Crabcorn soup and water"
    'and so on until i reach friday
End if
```

How do I do these in the following weeks but with different menus rather than repeating the same meal I eat in monday and etc? But it will repeat again when the next month comes?

Comment: That is upon you what you will have to do. There are plenty of solutions for those problems. That's why something like that is a nice homework :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Int32, DayofWeek), String)` where the key is a tuple, the first item is the week-number and the second item is the `DayOfWeek`:

```
Dim monthlyMeals = New Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Int32, DayofWeek), String) From 
    {  {Tuple.Create(1, DayOfWeek.Monday), "Steak with a cup of rice and Iced tea" }, {Tuple.Create(1, DayOfWeek.Tuesday), "Crabcorn soup and water" } }
```

Of course you have to fill this dictionary. Then you can use this code to find the todays meal:

```
Dim day = Date.Today
Dim dayTuple = Tuple.Create(GetWeekNumberOfday(day), day.DayOfWeek)
Dim todayMeal As String = Nothing
Dim mealIsDefined As Boolean = monthlyMeals.TryGetValue(dayTuple, todayMeal)
```

You need this method to get the week-number in a month of a given date:

```
Public Shared function GetWeekNumberOfDay(day as date)As Int32
    Dim dayOfWeekOfDay1 = new Date(day.Year, day.Month, 1).DayOfWeek
    dim offset = Math.Max(dayOfWeekOfDay1 - day.DayOfWeek, 0)
    Dim weekNumber As Integer = (day.Day - offset) \ 7 + 1
    Return weekNumber
End function
```

Additional task for you: create a class `Meal` which encapsulates it's `Name` and other useful properties and then use that as Value of the dictionary. Override `ToString` to return the `Name`.

Comment: Thankyou very much :)

Comment: uhmmm am I seeing things or you commented this "of course the code doesn't work or why don't you accept the answer"?